# Use a different color for notification number badge

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Currently it's red.

Taking into account its proximity to where the reputation change badge appears, the notification badge is easily misconstrued as "Oh no my reputation decreased!" not just on first glance but all the time because the inbox icon that is visible when there are no messages simply goes away with a red number badge in its place.

Why not blue? Or a yellow/orange? Anything but danger-zone red, really.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate for this somewhere, but as I understand it, this is intended behavior.

It's meant to catch your attention because someone is probably requesting more information or clarification from something that you've written, and it also stands as a contrast to the green so that you can know immediately what type of notification you've received (comment or reputation increase).

It shouldn't be too confusing once you realize that [you are not notified of negative reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/258672).

Comment: None of the suggested questions appear to be duplicates. Sorry if it is. In light of not being notified on negative reputation changes I can see how that design decision could have been made, however I still believe it is a bit alarming and there are better color options that will achieve the same attention catching effect.

Comment: @jlego It's probably a [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) duplicate, so it wouldn't be a problem even if I could find it.

Comment: @jlego [Here it is.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226232/why-is-the-inbox-notification-icon-red)

Comment: Wow. People getting up in arms about color choices!